# Is it possible to use a Fragment as MvpView inside an Activity using Mosby

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mvp, mosby

Is it possible to use a Fragment as MvpView inside an Activity using Mosby?

For example, this is a stripped-down version of [TaskDetailActivity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailActivity.java) in Google's todo-mvp-dagger project:

```
public class TaskDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_TASK_ID = "TASK_ID";

    @Inject TaskDetailPresenter mTaskDetailPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.taskdetail_act);

        // Get the requested task id
        String taskId = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TASK_ID);

        TaskDetailFragment taskDetailFragment = (TaskDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.contentFrame);

        if (taskDetailFragment == null) {
            taskDetailFragment = TaskDetailFragment.newInstance(taskId);

            ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    taskDetailFragment, R.id.contentFrame);
        }

        // Create the presenter
        DaggerTaskDetailComponent.builder()
                .taskDetailPresenterModule(new TaskDetailPresenterModule(taskDetailFragment, taskId))
                .tasksRepositoryComponent(((ToDoApplication) getApplication())
                .getTasksRepositoryComponent()).build()
                .inject(this);
    }       

    ...

}
```

In the example code, the Fragment is passed to the TaskDetailPresenterModule as a view instance. Is this possible using Mosby, and if so is it good practice? Can we place our presenter inside Activity and use the Fragment instead of the Activity as MvpView?

I am asking this because I also wonder how Mosby handles an Activity with multiple Fragments inside.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is possible, however, i dont see any advantage in doing so. Honestly, I dont understand why Google samples consider this way of setting up a presenter with a fragment as a recommended way...